# How to call a function when opening program from file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I made a project in visual studio 2010 (maybe a bit outdated but I like it this way).
With that project I made a separate project that handles the setup file for the installation. In this setup project I assigned a file type to my project so that the program can be started by double-clicking the file. 
Now all of this works, the file gets a icon similar to the program and when I double-click it, the program opens. The only problem is that it doesn't open the file that was clicked.
I think I need to change something in the 'command' that is seen in the file type properties. As it is, I just have it set to "Primary output form Project 1". How can I make it so that it doesn't just open the program, but also calls a function that loads the data inside the file?

I'm sorry if this question has been asked before. I searched for it but I couldn't find a similar question. I'm also pretty new to the whole programming thing.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post the code you are running where you are having a problem.  You can do this by editing your question.  Someone will be more likely to help you once you do.

Comment: That's the problem, all of this happens outside of the coding of my actual program. It's in the 'file type' properties in my setup project. It's where I assign a file type to my program so that the program can be opened by double-clicking the file. My program (in this case) starts with the standard cpp file of a Windows forms project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass the filename to your program as a command line argument.

Add `%1` to the end of the command you have associated with the file extension.

For example: `"C:\path\to\MyProgram" "%1"`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After I do this, how can I get this filename in my code? Is it stored in a certain variable?

Comment: It will be passed as a command line argument. How to retrieve it depends on what language you are working with and you did not provide code or tag with a language. In C/C++ for example, given the normal definition for main, you would have that value in `argv[1]`.

Comment: I'm using a Windows forms project in visual C++. I think I'll be able to get it to work now. Thanks for your answers!